# Undecidability in optimal data compression

Tags: turing-machines, undecidability, information-theory, data-compression

There is this certain slide in Coursera Computer Science: Algorithms, Theory, and Machines course:
[image]

I think it is saying finding the optimal size of given data is undecidable. However, I thought there is a theorem in information theory that gives the limit of the lossless compression? I think I must have misinterpreted something in this slide but I cannot tell what that is.

Comment: You can have a look at [Kolmogorov complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity) for more on this.

Comment: One is optimal size for a single string, the other is optimal expected size for a distribution over strings.

Answer (score 4):

The length of the shortest program to produce a given string is known as the [Kolmogorov complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity) of that given string. (Of course, some details are needed to give a formal definition, but this is the idea.) A proof of undecidability goes roughly as follows:

- There exist strings of arbitrary large Kolmogorov complexity by a counting argument: A program produces (at most) one string, and there are a finite number of program of length at most $N$, so a finite number of string of Kolmogorov complexity at most $N$;
- Assume that the Kolmogorov complexity of a string is computable. For any integer $N$, we can write a program that does the following: it enumerates all the strings (in some lexicographic order) until it finds one that has Kolmogorov complexity $\ge N$. The size of this program is roughly $O(\log N)$ (a constant number of instruction, and the value of $N$ hard-coded in the program).
- We conclude the string $s$ produced by the program of the preceding item satisfies two contradictory statements:

  - it has Kolmogorov complexity $\ge N$, that is the smallest program to produce it has length $\ge N$;
  - the program we describe has length $<N$ and produces $s$.

I don't know what you have in mind exactly concerning lossless compression, but it may be related to the first part of the proof sketch: It is not possible that all strings be compressible, because to each description corresponds one string.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%27s_source_coding_theorem states that lossless compression cannot have entropy less than certain threshold. Doesn't that correspond to the shortest program in some way?

Comment: The second bullet point is a bit hard to read, but it reminds me a lot of diagonalization, the halting problem, and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interesting_number_paradox .

Comment: @Zzy1130 Information theory only loosely apply here. That studies, roughly put, how to compress an unknown string generated by a known random source. In that setting you want the compressed value to have the shortest _average_ length, and theorems state that you can only compress so far (on average). By contrast, the undecidable problem you mentioned does not involve probability or averages: there is only a given string and you need to find the shortest program.

Comment: @Zzy1130 If you take a standard compression algorithm, and compress the string $s$, then a possible algorithm to generate $s$ is the application of the decompress algorithm to the compressed $s$. However, this is not optimal: if $s$ contains the first $10^{10}$ digits of $\pi$ the compressed $s$ is still very long, and much shorter algorithms exist.

Comment: I rewrote the second bullet. And yes, it has a lot to do with diagonalization.